# Prevent the user from saving twice

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I have this code to save data to database on click of button

```
private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var row = dt.Rows[i];

        await paint.Add_PartShipping(Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]), Convert.ToInt32(row["Quantité"]),
                                     Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"])).ConfigureAwait(true);
    }
    XtraMessageBox.Show(Resources.addMes, Resources.add, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
 }
```

and this is the code behind

```
public async Task Add_PartShipping(int FK_idPartShip, int Quantity, DateTime CreationDate)
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    await Task.Run(() => DAL.Open()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];

    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@FK_idPartShip", SqlDbType.Int)
    {
        Value = FK_idPartShip
    };

    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int)
    {
        Value = Quantity
    };

    param[2] = new SqlParameter("@CreationDate", SqlDbType.Date)
    {
        Value = CreationDate
    };

   await Task.Run(() => DAL.ExcuteCommande("Add_PartShipping", param)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    DAL.Close();
}
```

The problem began to appear when a user encountered a problem with their mouse, where you click twice automatically then the data save twice.

How can I prevent this behavior when the user actually clicks twice.

Comment: `btnSave.Enabled = false` at the beginning method. `btnSave.Enabled = true` at the end.

Comment: One simple idea is to compare with the previously saved data, if are the same, do not save the new one.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what exactly you are asking… for starters, your comment… _”The problem began to appear when a user encountered a problem with their mouse, where you click twice automatically then the data save twice.”_ … this sounds like a “mouse” problem… then fix the mouse! … next, your comment … _”How can I prevent this behavior when the user actually clicks twice.”_ ? this sounds odd in a sense that “IF” the user actually clicked twice, then what are you trying to prevent? The user “intended” to click twice, yet you want code that prevents the second click? This is odd.

Comment: It seems like you want the code to “read” the users mind by saying that the user did NOT intend to click the button twice! The main point here is that If the user clicked the button twice, there is no way your code is going to know if the user did it intentionally or not. On the second click of the button let us assume the same data is overwritten… then so be it. It will be “more” work to check if the data is the same, than to simply overwrite it with the same data.

Comment: One possible solution is to “disable” the save button when the data is loaded. If the data changes, then “enable” the save button. When the save button is clicked, save the data then “disable” the save button until the data changes again. Obviously, this will require that the code checks and sets the button to “enabled” once the user makes a change to the data.